# 文了 也温了 any ideas?

Tags: translation

I'm hoping to work my way through the Chinese tv series 新结婚时代, looking up new vocab, learning it as I go and I'm hoping to understand it all as I work through it.

Already in the first few lines I've come across the following dialogue which is rather hard to work out:

> 书名肯定不行
>   卖不出去
>   人比黄花
>   文了
>   也温了

- The name of the book certainly won't do
- It'll never sell
- ?
- ?
- ?

I understand that the name of the book is probably untranslatable as it's some literary reference... but any ideas about the last two lines?

Comment: can you tell me which episode it is when you came across these lines? I want to review it to find more context, so I can give you a more 'precise' answer.

Comment: @Huang: It is the [first episode](http://bbs.wenxuecity.com/renzainiuyue/276695.html).

Comment: I just watched it, and I agree with @gonnastop.

Comment: As a native Chinese writer, I don't know what the last three lines talk about.

Comment: Can we fix the title? Make it an actual question.

Answer (score 8):

> 书名肯定不行 The book title doesn't work.
>
> 卖不出去 It won't sell well.
>
> 人比黄花 (The title comes from "人比黄花瘦.") *See notes below.*
>
> 文了 (literally) It's too "academic." (Only those trained in classics
>   would understand.)
>
> 也温了 It's also too vague. (温 means "not too hot and not too cold (lukewarm)." I think the man is trying to say that the title doesn't hit the sweet spot: it's "in-between" and needs more work.)
>
> 指向性不明 Readers don't know what you are referring to. (This line helps you understand "也温了.")

Notes on "人比黄花" (which comes from "人比黄花瘦")

From [Baidu Baike](http://baike.baidu.com/view/106130.htm)

> “人比黄花瘦”出自李清照前期的作品《醉花阴》，作品表面上是写深秋佳节孤独寂寞的心绪，实则表达了重阳节思念丈夫的心情。这个词语用来比喻人憔悴，暗示相思之深。

Rough translation:

> 人比黄花瘦 comes from a [词 (ci2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci_%28poetry%29) written by 李清照 (li3 qing1 zhao4). "黄花"
>   is "菊花", chrysanthemum. "瘦" is thin. The poet compares herself with
>   the flower to illustrate her weary look (because she misses her
>   husband dearly).

In 《新结婚时代》, after the man refused to use the title "人比黄花", the editor (girl in pink with a ponytail) joked about changing it to "地下通道的无头女尸" (headless body found in the tunnel), which is more literal and "catchy."

Comment: This is a good example of "标题党" that is very common to see in network and media nowadays. A "good" title to attract the readers.

Comment: @Huang Indeed! Feel free to edit my answer!

Comment: @gonnastop Interesting explanation, thx.

Answer (score -1):

> 书名肯定不行

The title of the book is not good at all.

> 卖不出去

It doesn't help promoting selling.

> 人比黄花

人比黄花 (Is this the title of the book?)

> 文了
>   也温了

gonnastop explained very well.